# Function where variable is integration bound

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

Lets say I have a function of the form:

$f(T) = T^4 \int_0^{1/T} \frac{x^3 dx}{e^x-1}$

This is an example of the situation I am describing not a unique problem.

I want to define it as a numerical function so I can manipulate it.  For example, I might plot it.

Doing the following gets the plot of the function:

```
int[T_] = NIntegrate[x^3/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, 1/T}];
Plot[T^4*int[T], {T, 0., 1.}]
```

But my function isn't really a general function.  I can't take a derivative of it successfully.  Mathematica spits out errors at me because my function definition is flawed somehow.

How do I get a function that I can use in all of the ways numerical functions can be used in Mathematica?

I also would like to generalize this beyond the simple example given.

Comment: The [Debye function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DebyeFunctions.html) is expressible in terms of built-in functions: `debye[t_] := {-t, 3 t^2, -6 t^3, 6 t^4}.PolyLog[Range[4], Exp[1/t]] - (π t)^4/15 - 1/4`.

Comment: FWIW just using `Integrate` (w/ `Assumptions -> T > 0`)  gives an analytic result. ( A little different from the above, but I expect equivalent )

Comment: I love that everyone immediately recognized the Debye function.

Comment: You could use a pure function `int = NIntegrate[x^3/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, 1/#}] &`, you can calculate it's arbitrary derivative e.g. `int''[T]` gives $\frac{5}{\left(e^{1/T}-1\right) T^6}-\frac{e^{1/T}}{\left(e^{1/T}-1\right)^2 T^7}$, you can also plot it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[f]

f[t_] = Assuming[{t > 0},
  t^4*Integrate[x^3/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, 1/t}] //
   Simplify]

(*  -(1/4) + I*Pi*t - (Pi^4*t^4)/15 + 
   t*Log[-1 + E^(1/t)] + 3*t^2*PolyLog[2, E^(1/t)] - 
   6*t^3*PolyLog[3, E^(1/t)] + 
   6*t^4*PolyLog[4, E^(1/t)]  *)

tmax = 1.5;
Show[
 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Blue, Red},
    {"f[t]", "f'[t]"}]],
 Plot[f'[t] // Chop, {t, 0, tmax},
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotPoints -> 50],
 ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotRange -> {0, 0.35}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If  $f(T) = T^4\int_0^{1/T} \frac{x^3}{e^x-1}dx$.
Then you can differentiate it by parts which gives you

```
Cv[t_] := -1/(t*(Exp[1/t] - 1)) + (4*t^3*NIntegrate[x^3/(Exp[x] - 1), {x, 0, 1/t}])

Plot[Cv[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I can do work by hand, but I would like to generalize this this beyond the Debye function.  So it works for any function defined in terms of an integration bound.